# compiling actionscript in linux

Tags: linux, actionscript, command-line

I'm working on a website that requires a flash mp3 player. I have absolutely no idea the procedures from messing with flash/actionscript/flex etc., however I need to edit the flash very slightly (I need to add two lines of code). There are a multitude of tutorials out there for setting up a flash (or flex or whatever) development environment but, as my needs are so simple, I'd like to go a little more light-weight than that (also, many seem outdated). I guess what I'm saying is I'm looking for a simple way to recompile some existing actionscript (command line is a plus!). Does anyone have a trick up their sleeve to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the free/opensource [Flex 3 SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3). This includes an ActionScript3 compiler. Run the compiler like this:

```
mxmlc MyAs3File.as
```

Comment: Thanks man. That's exactly what I needed, except I'm trying to compile something written in actionscript2. I assume this would produce errors?

Comment: Did you try MTASC? If that fails, find somebody with MacOS or Windows (or install it yourself in a virtual machine), and compile in Flash CS. A demo version is available at adobe.com.

Comment: mxmlc can only compile ActionScript3 class files and Flex MXML files.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile it online here: http://wonderfl.kayac.com/. No mess that way.

Answer (score 1):

There's [MTASC](http://mtasc.org/) for ActionScript 2.

Comment: I'm under the impression they have actionscript 3 out now. Wouldn't I want to compile with the latest standards? What's the difference?

Comment: Yes, Adobe have released version 3, but MTASC supports only ActionScript 2, like it says on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to say that [swftools](http://swftools.org) has exactly what you need. There is a swfc compiler which will compile as2 files. I would really recommend updating the source though. AS3 is much faster than AS2 and there are a lot of tools out there for example mxmlc and fcsh included in the [open source Flex sdk](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+4.6). If you are looking for a full blown IDE there is a linux version of Flash Builder that was released as an [open source port](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/) ... there are a couple other ones out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### General Linux

On `linux` you can [get the source from swftools.org](http://www.swftools.org/).

#### Debian / Ubuntu

On `debian` / `ubuntu` you can run

```
apt-get install swftools
```

#### Mac OS X

Not exactly 'linux' but on `mac OS X` if you have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed you can do:

```
brew install swftools
```

#### Great, but how do I compile the code?

One this is installed you should have a new utility that you can use to do:

```
as3compile MyAs3File.as
```

#### Gotchas

Please note this is not a 1:1 replacement for Adobe's compiler - there are some things that it does not support ( see documentation, FAQ, changelog at swftools.org ) but it worked well for compiling my simple actionscript.