# Compiling actionscript on linux

Tags: linux, flash, actionscript, compilation

I want to make a few little changes to an open source flash charts library. 
In the source there are .fla files and .as files. After editing one of the .as files, 
I want to recompile, but I don't know how to do this. The charts library is [dv charts](http://dv-charts.com/en/home/).

I googled and found this topic here: [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775526/compiling-actionscript-in-linux). I tried using mxmlc as described, but that comes with the error

> bash: ./mxmlc: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

So I want to know if there's an easy way to recompile after making a few changes to the actionscript files? Should I use mxmlc or are there any alternatives.. ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a virtualization software, I'd say FlashDevelop. It can't recompile your FLA, only your AS classes though.
http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Features

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing from scratch you can us MXMLC to compile your actionscript with the open-source Flex SDK - since you have revisions to an FLA you need an actual version of Flash Pro to compile those. Your best bet, if this is a continuing project would be to save out your assets to a SWC from Flash Pro then embed it into your AS project that way. From there, you can use MXMLC to compile your project.